# Unbiased estimator from a random sample

Tags: statistics, variance, sampling, parameter-estimation

**Problem**

I really don't understand the answer to the below question. It's only 2 marks, so it should be reasonably simple.

**Attempt**

I have expanded out the brackets and got as far as $E(Y) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$ but it feels very lengthy.

**Question**

[image]

Comment: Do you recognize that $\frac{8}{7} Y$ is the typical unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$?

Comment: Try expanding $S^2=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{i=1}^{8}(X_i-\overline{X})^2$.

Comment: @angryavian Unfortunately i'm really struggling with this topic tbh. The official textbook for my course barely mentions estimates of this type. It only mentions S^2 = 1/n-1 Sum of X^2 - X^2/n formula but that doesn't apply here. I also have the Crawshaw book but that doesn't seem to explain it?

Comment: If you want to close this question fine, but it would be appreciated if you could point me towards another source to help.

Comment: @angryavian I've just noticed the formula in the question looks very similar to the original formula of the one in my comment.

Comment: @MatthewH. but I will end-up with a -2(product of them both) coefficient?

Comment: Note $$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{I=1}^8-2X_i\overline{X}&=&-2\overline{X}\sum_{I=1}^8X_i \\&=&-2\overline{X}\cdot 8\overline{X}\\&=&-16\overline{X}^2\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @MatthewH. Not sure that helped tbh. I can see the formula in the question is very similar to S^2 = 1/n+1 x sum(x^2) - n(x_^2) but that's as far as I can get.

Comment: I'll post an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$\begin{eqnarray*}S^2&=&\frac{1}{7}\sum_{k=1}^8(X_k-\overline{X})^2\\&=&\frac{1}{7}\left[\sum_{k=1}^8X_k^2-2\overline{X}\sum_{k=1}^8X_k+8\overline{X}^2\right] \\ &=& \frac{1}{7}\left[\sum_{k=1}^8X_k^2-2\overline{X}\cdot 8\overline{X}+8\overline{X}^2\right]\\&=&\frac{1}{7}\left[\sum_{k=1}^8X_k^2-8\overline{X}^2\right] \\ &=& \frac{8}{7}Y \end{eqnarray*}$$ So, $$\sigma^2=\mathbb{E}(S^2)=\frac{8}{7}\mathbb{E}(Y) \implies \mathbb{E}(Y)={7\sigma^2 \over 8} $$

Comment: Okay, managed to do it slightly differently, based on your answer. I used the other formula, 1/n-1 x sum(x^2) minus (nx_^2).